# Calling JS function not working

Tags: javascript, html, function

can anyone of you be so kind as to help me find out why this isn't working?
Trying to implement a function in JavaScript that gets called whenever I press Submit. So far nothing happens when I press submit.

I found this code on a webpage https://jsfiddle.net/aconyteds/aQJza/ and so I wanted to try to implement this my self/play around with it and learn from it. But I can't figure out why it's not working.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Choose your faction!</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
(function(){
    function gId(s){return document.getElementById(s);}
    var character={
    faction:["Alliance", "Horde"],
    race:{"Alliance":["Dwarf","Gnome","Human","Night Elf","Dranei", "Worgen","Pandaren"], 
          "Horde":["Orc","Troll","Tauren","Undead","Blood Elf","Goblin","Pandaren"]},
    class:{"Dranei":["Death Knight","Hunter","Mage","Paladin","Priest","Shaman","Warrior","Monk"], 
           "Dwarf":["Death Knight","Hunter","Mage","Paladin","Priest","Rogue","Shaman","Warlock","Warrior","Monk"], 
           "Gnome":["Death Knight","Mage","Priest","Rogue","Warlock","Warrior","Monk"], 
           "Human":["Death Knight","Hunter","Mage","Paladin","Priest","Rogue","Warlock","Warrior","Monk"], 
           "Night Elf":["Death Knight","Druid","Hunter","Mage","Priest","Rogue","Warrior","Monk"],
           "Worgen":["Death Knight","Druid","Hunter","Mage","Priest","Rogue","Warlock","Warrior"], 
           "Blood Elf":["Death Knight","Hunter","Mage","Paladin","Priest","Rogue","Warlock","Warrior","Monk"],
           "Undead":["Death Knight","Hunter","Mage","Priest","Rogue","Warlock","Warrior","Monk"], 
           "Goblin":["Death Knight","Hunter","Mage","Priest","Rogue","Shaman","Warlock","Warrior"], 
           "Orc":["Death Knight","Hunter","Mage","Rogue","Shaman","Warlock","Warrior","Monk"], 
           "Tauren":["Death Knight","Druid","Hunter","Paladin","Priest","Shaman","Warrior","Monk"], 
           "Troll":["Death Knight","Druid","Hunter","Mage","Priest","Rogue","Shaman","Warlock","Warrior","Monk"],
           "Pandaren":["Warrior","Hunter","Rogue","Priest","Shaman","Mage","Monk"]},
    spec:{"Death Knight":["Blood","Frost","Unholy"],
          "Druid":["Balance","Feral","Guardian","Restoration"],
          "Hunter":["Beastmaster","Marksmanship","Survival"],
          "Mage":["Arcane","Fire","Frost"],
          "Monk":["Brewmaster","Mistweaver","Windwalker"],
          "Paladin":["Holy","Protection","Retribution"],
          "Priest":["Discipline","Holy","Shadow"],
          "Rogue":["Assassination","Combat","Subtlety"],
          "Shaman":["Elemental","Enhancement","Restoration"],
          "Warlock":["Affliction","Demonology","Destruction"],
          "Warrior":["Arms","Fury","Protection"]}
    };
    gId("Submit").onclick=function(){
        var c={faction:"",race:"",sex:"",class:"",spec:""};
        c.faction=gId("Faction").value==="Random"?_Select(character.faction):gId("Faction").value;
        c.race=_Select(character.race, c.faction);
        c.sex=_Select(["Male","Female"]);
        c.class=_Select(character.class, c.race);
        c.spec=_Select(character.spec, c.class);
        function _Select(obj,param){
            var t=param?obj[param]:obj;
            return t[Math.floor(Math.random()*t.length)]; 
        }
        gId("Output").innerHTML=c.faction+" "+c.sex+" "+c.race+" "+c.spec+" "+c.class;
    }
})();
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- <p id="mypara">demo</p>
<button type="button" onclick="funcClick()">Martin</button> -->

<p>World of Warcraft Random Character Selector.</p>
<p>Select your faction, then press submit to generate your random Character.</p>
<div>
    <select id="Faction">
        <option value="Random">Random</option>
        <option value="Alliance">Alliance</option>
        <option value="Horde">Horde</option>        
    </select>
    <button id="Submit">Submit</button>
</div>
<p id="Output"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Nothing happens when I press the submit button.

Comment: Elements have to exist on the page before you can bind to them. Consider moving the script to the bottom of the page or, optionally, wrap it in an event handler targeting the `DOMContentLoaded` event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You load and run your script before you load the rest of the document, so the button isn't loaded and nothing happens. To fix this, consider putting your code at the bottom of the body tag

Answer (score -1):

Place your code inside Document Ready Event (i.e `$(document).ready(function(){ //Your code will be here});` so that DOM will be ready to register events

**OR**

Put all the script after DOM body